# An example of an easy to understand undecidable problem

Tags: logic, examples-counterexamples

I am looking for an undecidable problem that I could give as an easy example in a presentation to the general public. I mean easy in the sense that the mathematics behind it can be described, well, without mathematics, that is with analogies and intuition, avoiding technicalities.

Comment: The formula $\forall x, y \quad xy=xy$ is undecidable in the theory describing the usual group theory.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

**"Are these two real numbers** (or functions, or grammars, or mathematical statements) **equivalent?"**
*(See also [word problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_problem_%28mathematics%29))*

**"Does this statement follow from these axioms?"**
*(Hilbert's [Entscheidungsproblem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entscheidungsproblem))*

**"Does this computer program ever stop?"**
**"Does this computer program have any security vulnerabilities?"**
**"Does this computer program do <any non-trivial statement>?"**
*(The [halting-problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem), from which [all semantic properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem) can be reduced)*

**"Can this set of domino-like tiles tile the plane?"**
*(See [Tiling Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wang_tile))*

**"Does this [Diophantine equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation) have an integer solution?"**
*(See [Hilbert's Tenth Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_tenth_problem))*

**"Given two lists of strings, is there a list of indices such that the concatenations from both lists are equal?"**
*(See [Post correspondence problem](http://www.loopycode.com/a-surprisingly-hard-problem-post-correspondence/))*

---

There is also a large list on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_undecidable_problems).

Comment: Wikipedia's explanation of the proof of undecidability for the halting problem is really bad.

Comment: Regarding the first example, it's important to consider how you're specifying real numbers. For example, the first-order arithmetic of real numbers is complete; one can always decide, and do so algorithmically, whether two real numbers are equal when they're sepcified in the language of first-order real arithmetic. (also called real-closed fields)

Comment: I know this is ancient, but the final example here (Post's correspondence problem) is dealt with better in another answer, below, and was only edited in here a full month after that answer was posted.

Answer (score 7):

I think the [Post correspondence problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_correspondence_problem) is a very good example of a simple undecideable problem that is also relatively unknown.

Given a finite set of string tuples, each with an index $i$, a left string $l(i)$ and a right string $r(i)$, the problem is to determine if there is a finite sequence of index values $i(1),i(2),\dots,i(n)$, allowing for repetition, such that the concatenation of the left strings $l(i(1)),\dots,l(i(n))$ is equal to the concatenation of the corresponding right strings $r(i(1)),\dots,r(i(n))$. For example, with three tuples with $(l(i), r(i)), i$ as follows:

```
(a , baa) X
(ab,  aa) Y
(bba, bb) Z
```

we may use the index sequence $Z, Y, Z, X$:

```
(bba, bb) Z
(ab,  aa) Y
(bba, bb) Z
(a,  baa) X
------------ gives
(bbaabbbaa, bbaabbbaa)
```

The only big issue I have with this problem is that the only undecideability proof I know of falls back on simulating a Turing machine --- it would be nice to find a more elementary alternate version.

Comment: there is a typo (a,bba) instead of (a,baa) for tuple 1. but it is not allowed to change only one character

Comment: @miracle173. Thanks! (btw, if I remember correctly you can add invisible html comments `<!-- -->` to bypass the edit size limit if you need to fix typos in the future)

Comment: The PCP can be reduced to the word problem for semigroups (and, more generally, for rewriting systems). This gives a more elementary proof of undecidability, if you are willing to accept that the word problem for semigroups/rewriting systems is undecidable! See Harju T., Karhumäki J. (1997) *Morphisms*. In: Rozenberg G., Salomaa A. (eds) Handbook of Formal Languages. Springer, Berlin, Heidelberg.

Answer (score 4):

"does this computer program ever stop?"

"does this equation have any solutions?" (of course you mean polynomial equation with integer solutions, but for a general public presentation you can probably get away with just "equation" and "solutions").

Answer (score 4):

May be you want to check these:

[Alan_Turing_and_Undecidable_Problems_in_Mathematics](http://fora.tv/2011/05/17/Alan_Turing_and_Undecidable_Problems_in_Mathematics) on fora.tv

[what-are-the-most-attractive-turing-undecidable-problems-in-mathematics](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/11540/what-are-the-most-attractive-turing-undecidable-problems-in-mathematics) on mathoverflow

[MagicSquare](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MagicSquare.html) on mathworld.wolfram

Comment: Link rot happens. Imagine someone cannot click on any links, and consider how useful your answer will be.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: Thanks for you suggestion. Do you prefer placing the text of the url instead?

Comment: Please do not post answers which force people to click on the links to know what they contain. See the simple way I used to avoid this by consulting the modified source of your post.

Comment: @DidierPiau: Thank you for your comment and clear instructions.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe consider some [Wang Tiles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wang_tile).