# Imaginary number in relativistic speeds

Tags: complex-numbers, general-relativity

I am layman in field of mathematics but when I was reading about theory of special relativity I have come across speed limit of light and the book said that no one can cross that limit because $\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}$, here $v$= speed of object so if object possess that velocity answer is imaginary number which is not possible. So my question is that why we need imaginary number number in mathematics in first place and what is its application in real world?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where is the world of Imaginary numbers?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/633189/where-is-the-world-of-imaginary-numbers)