# Is there an infinite number of number sets? (natural, integers, real, complex...)

Tags: complex-numbers, quaternions

I've heard of a number set on that's the smallest set after complex numbers, according to http://www.askamathematician.com/2012/09/q-is-there-a-number-set-that-is-above-complex-numbers/ (The Physicist) called **quaternions**.

A comment on that article says that there is another set called **dual numbers**, that's used to rendering fractals in graphics and even have equivalent quaternions, as stated by blackhole0173.

I wonder if there are more number sets to discover!

Comment: For each prime $p$, I would count the $p$-adic numbers $\mathbb{Z}_p$, or $\mathbb{Q}_p$, as a "number set" which makes infinitely many.  Also, any number field such as $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{n})$ for $n \ne 1$ square-free, or its ring of integers, would count as a "number set" in my book.

Comment: you might be interested to read about the [Cayley-Dickson construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Dickson_construction).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your question is that nobody knows what a "number set" is.  The way I interpret it, each positive integer $n$ creates a "number set" of modular arithmetic mod $n$, and there are infinitely many, so yes.

If you were just thinking of fields/division rings, then there's always infinite towers of fields, e.g. infinitely many subfields of the algebraic closure of the field of two elements.

I would encourage you to do a little bit of reading [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/865409/29335) about what concepts are used in mathematics that are colloquially referred to as "numbers", so that you become more familiar with the issue.