# Why was $i$ introduced to satisfy this $\sqrt{-1}$?

Tags: complex-numbers

Can someone explain to me why $$\sqrt{-1} = i$$ I love math and I'm looking at doing it to higher levels. I know that we can NEVER have a square root of a negative number as per my reading hence if I was given $$\sqrt{-4}$$ the answer would be $$2i$$
and if I was given
$$\sqrt{4}$$ 
the answer would be $\pm2$, can I get sources explaining why $i$ was introduced?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for an explanation here (as in your first sentence) or a source (as in your next-to-last sentence)?

Comment: Yes that is what i want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, $i \neq \sqrt{-1}$. $i$ is simply a symbol that we use to denote a solution to the equation $z^2 + 1 = 0 \iff z^2 = -1$. This symbol is called the imaginary unit and there isn't really a reason **why** it represents a solution to $z^2 = -1$, it's more that it was **defined** to be that way. This imaginary unit is quite important in the field of mathematics. It extends the real numbers and generates the complex number system that has quite a significant impact on mathematics. Examples include a whole branch of analysis termed complex analysis or provides algebraic closure for polynomials in $\mathbb{C}$.

Secondly, $\sqrt{4} \neq \pm 2$. The square root function denoted by the radical sign refers to **only** the positive value, which is why technically $i \neq \sqrt{-1}$ and why $\sqrt{4} = 2$ and not $-2$.

As for why the imaginary number was introduced, there are a multitude of reasons. For example, the introduction of such a number means that the field of real numbers is algebraically closed. Specifically, the algebraic closure of the real numbers is the field of complex numbers that are generated by including $i$. A lot about the usage and technicalities of the imaginary unit $i$ can be gleaned from its Wikipedia page [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_unit), that I would encourage you to read.

Comment: This is wonderful info. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

on the history, my impression is that people were fairly happy having quadratic equations without (realnumber) roots. Then for cubic equations, Cardano, about 1545, introduced a rudimentary version of complex numbers, because his method lead directly to using cube roots of one of these objects.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number

good book: http://www.maa.org/publications/periodicals/convergence/an-imaginary-tale-the-story-of-1
from the book description:

> The solution of cubic equations in the sixteenth century forced
>   mathematicians to deal with the square root of -1, and in the first
>   major chapter of the book, the author handles this episode judiciously
>   and leisurely.

Comment: I am Fascinated by mathematics and i really want complex numbers not to give me hard time. Hence i decided to look into this. Thanks for the link

Comment: From my recollection of the history, part of the issue was that algebra was not exactly well-developed in Italian mathematics at that point. Instead they typically framed things geometrically; for example, the quadratic equation $x^2-3x+2=0$ might have instead been interpreted as the equality in area of different combinations of squares. That makes it easy enough to dismiss equations like $x^2+1=0$, since one would simply say "no such arrangement exists." (cont).

Comment: What forced the issue re: imaginary numbers was that, when one tackles the cubic case, there are cases which 1) Cardan's formula introduces square roots of negative numbers, and yet 2) if one treats $\sqrt{-1}$ seriously, then once one carries out all the algebraic manipulations then one ends up with _real_ solutions. And that's not so easily dismissed, since these would amount to genuine geometric solutions. So imaginary numbers, even as they seemed nonsensical, were nevertheless quite _useful_. [This link](http://www.ms.uky.edu/~sohum/ma330/files/eqns_2.pdf) nicely discusses the history.

Comment: @Semiclassical, I thought you were leading up to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis which the chapter does not mention, or I did  not recognize it there.

Comment: The _casus irreducibilis_ shows up in section 4.3 of the linked pdf, though only in passing. But it plays the central role in the [third part](http://www.ms.uky.edu/~sohum/ma330/files/eqns_3.pdf) of that same set of notes.