# Classifying the imaginary numbers?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

We classify the real numbers into subsets, so I thought is it fruitful or even used to classify the imaginary or complex numbers as well?

I mean for example something like this:

$$\pi+i\pi \qquad(\text{real-real})$$
$$3+i\frac{1}{245} \qquad(\text{natural-rational})$$

Or is this a useless thoughts since there are some fancy complex properties who make it a useless decision?

Comment: Sure, you can do it, but what's the point?

Comment: I'm sure some aspects of what you're asking about have already been described. For instance: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integer

Comment: If you're gonna classify $\pi+i\pi$ as real-real, I have doubts about how interesting anything you prove will be.

Comment: Is it possible to have (odd + i odd)^2 = (even + i even) ? in naturals it is easy to see that odd^2 is always odd, maybe this classification can be used to classify results like that?

Comment: @Arjang Not only is it possible, but it is so in every case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We classify the real numbers because it is natural to do so from an algebraic and analytic standpoint. Algebraically, the integers form a ring, the rational numbers form the field of fractions of the whole numbers, and from an analytic standpoint, the irrational numbers are what you thrown in to get a complete field. This is done to some point with complex numbers; for instance, the *Gaussian integers* are those of the form $a+bi$, where a and b are integers, and the *algebraic numbers* are those which satisfy a polynomial with $\mathbb{Z}$ coefficients. However to classify them more than that does not really help out so much. But yes, you could do it!

Edit: I am linking to this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/199688/223701 by Clive Newstead because it deals with this categorification in a much better way than I could do so.

Comment: @Hurkyl thanks for the catch, I always get confused with the terms. Will edit