# Why complex $i^2=-1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Multiplying $2$ times a real number gives $n \cdot n$ positive:

$2^2 =2\cdot2 =4$

But multiply $2$ times $i$ gives $-1$:

$i^2 =i\cdot i=-1$

Shouldn't $i \cdot i $ give $i^2$?

Does $i \cdot i = -1 \cdot 1$?

Comment: What is your definition of $i$?

Comment: Yes, $i\cdot i=i^2$ and $i^2=-1$.

Comment: By definition, $i = \sqrt{-1}.$ And $  i^2 = (\sqrt{-1})^2 = -1.$  Note, $i$ is NOT a real number.  If it were, $i=\sqrt{-1}$ would be undefined.  $i$ is a complex number, not real.

Comment: $x^2 = -1$ has no solutions in reals, and $\,2x = 1$ has no solutions in integers. In both cases we can *extend* these number systems ([rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics))) to obtain another number system of similar algebraic structure (rings) which has solutions of these equations, viz. $\Bbb C = $ complex numbers, $\,\Bbb Q = $ rationals or fractions, and this proves fruitful: working in these extended numbers systems  [often simplifies](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/199771/242) results in our original number system.

Answer (score 5):

> multiplying $2$ times a real number gives $n \cdot n$
>   positive.
>
> $2^2 =2 \cdot 2 =4$

This is called *squaring*, not multiplying by $2$. Multiplying by $2$ would be, for example: $2 \cdot 5 = 10$, $2 \cdot 3 = 6$.

Squaring is different than multiplying by $2$: $5^2 = 5 \cdot 5 = 25$, $3^2 = 3 \cdot 3 = 9$.

> but multiply $2$ times $i$ gives $-1$
>
> $i^2 =i \cdot i=-1$

Yes, *squaring* $i$ gives $-1$. Isn't that strange? This is why $i$ is a new number: all the previous numbers square to get a positive number, and $i$ squares to get a negative number.

> shouldn't $i \cdot i $ give $i^2$?

Yes it does! But $i^2$ is also equal to $-1$, just like $3^2$ is also equal to $9$.

Comment: Isn't squaring rather a special case of multiplication?

Comment: @PratikApshinge Yes, that's true

Comment: @PratikApshinge In some contexts, squaring can be interpreted as a special case of multiplication.  On the other hand, it can also be seen as a special case of exponentiation, where the exponential function is defined in more abstract ways (e.g. $u(x) = \mathrm{e}^x$ is the unique solution to the BVP $u' = u$ with $u(0) = 1$; or $\mathrm{e}^x$ can be defined in terms of a series expansion).  In any event, when you square a number, you are *not* multiplying by $2$; you are multiplying a number by *itself*.

Answer (score 2):

Since, by definition, $x^2$ *means* $x\times x$, yes, $i^2=i\times i$.

And $i^2=-1$ because we define $i$ so that $i^2=-1$.

Finally, the fact that the product of a real number by itself is always positive is not relevant here, since $i$ is not a real number.

Answer (score 2):

The number $i$ was defined such that $i^2=-1$, so as a consequence, $i=\sqrt{-1}$. Because we are in the complex plane, we can no longer use the rules used in the real plane.

$i^2 \neq 1$, because $i=\sqrt{-1}$ $\notin$ $\mathbb R$, because $\forall$ $x$ $\in$ $\mathbb R$, $x^2 \ge 0$.

Answer (score 1):

The most interesting question is "why $i^2=-1 $ ?".

It turns out that mathematicians were a little "frustrated" that some polynomial equations like

$$x^2+1=0$$

seem to have no solutions. Then they "arbitrarily" decided that this equation had a solution, called it $i$, so that

$$i^2+1=0$$

(if you prefer, $i^2=-1$).

From this they discovered that using $i$ and reals, you can in fact solve *all* polynomials in the world. They also discovered many other interesting and useful properties and that gave birth to the powerful theory of complex numbers.

Comment: This is an oversimplification. Mathematicians where not bothered at all by quadratic equations with no solutions. Instead they were *very much* concerned with cubic equations *with* solutions, but where Cardano’s formula required to use square roots of negative numbers.

Comment: @egreg: yes, this is willingly an oversimplification and historical nonsense. The pedagogical goal is to (try to) give the OP a taste of why we use complex numbers.

Answer (score 1):

As much as we have that: $$\underbrace{a\cdot a\cdot \ldots\cdot a}_{n\text{ times}}=a^n\tag{1.1}$$
(which is the general rule you are using), we also have the corollary (by replacing $a$ with $a^\frac1n$):
$$\underbrace{a^\frac1n\cdot a^\frac1n\cdot \ldots\cdot a^\frac1n}_{n\text{ times}}=a\tag{1.2}$$

The imaginary unit $i$ is defined by $i^2=-1\implies i=(-1)^\frac12$

and so inserting $a=-1, n=2$ into $(1.2)$ yields your answer