# What is the use of imaginary number?

Tags: complex-numbers, prime-numbers

From origination point of view, if i understand correctly, we 'derived' imaginary number mathematically e.g. `x^2 = -1`. But what is the use of such number in study of mathematics? Are they really helpful in solving some problems or understanding some other problems or its just some useless observation by some mathematician?

Disclaimer: I'm not mathematician. I didnt get answers in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170334/whats-the-precise-meaning-of-imaginary-number)

Comment: Real numbers aren't algebraically closed, i.e. there are polynomials with real coefficients without real roots; however, all complex polynomials have complex roots.

Comment: See also: [What are imaginary numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/199676/272831)

Comment: $i$ is a stepping stone. It can be used to simply otherwise difficult calculations, also has intellectual interest. A slight analogy in chemistry, where a *catalyst* facilitates a reaction.

Comment: You might like this classic, [The Unreasonable Effectiveness of Mathematics in the Natural Sciences](https://www.dartmouth.edu/~matc/MathDrama/reading/Wigner.html)