# Why $\mathbb{R}$ is a subset of $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let us define $\mathbb{C}$ by
$$\mathbb{C} = \mathbb{R}^2.$$
Real elements of $\mathbb{C}$ are tuples $(x, 0)$. But $x \neq (x, 0)$, so $\mathbb{R}$ cannot be a subset of $\mathbb{C}$.

I also read the following definition. Let
$$\mathbb{C} = \{ a + bi \mid a, b \in \mathbb{R},\ i^2 = -1 \}.$$
But there is no $i \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $i^2 = -1$, so where does $i$ come from? If $i \in \mathbb{C}$ then we are using $\mathbb{C}$ in definition of $\mathbb{C}$.

NOTE: Apparently, there are similar questions on MSE but I think that lhf's answer is the best and most concise. Also, title "R is a subset of C?" is much easier to google than "Is a+0i in every way equal to just a?" I don't want readers to be redirected.

Comment: Think about the second definition. In what sense could $\mathbb{R}$ be considered a subset?

Comment: Also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/464262/why-is-there-never-a-proof-that-extending-the-reals-to-the-complex-numbers-will

Comment: Well, it seems to me that you've trouble with the definition of $\mathbb{R}$ and not the one of $\mathbb{C}$... Actually $\mathbb{R}$ is well defined and so you are not reaching any sort of contradiction when you're saying $\mathbb{R} \subset \mathbb{C}$ "because of the definition of $\mathbb{C}$". It's not because it seems too easy that it isn'tthat easy. If you really want to understand this more deeply, maybe you may try looking up for the way we are constructing $\mathbb{R}$. However the way Dedeking defines it is tricky and may not help you.

Comment: If you haven't seen this yet, it'll be instructive: [Matrix representation of complex numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Matrix_representation_of_complex_numbers).

Comment: Defining $\Bbb C$ as $\Bbb R^2$ seems like a bad idea, as $\Bbb R^2$ is only naturally a vector space. As you've mentioned $i^2 = -1$, you clearly intend to multiply things in $\Bbb C$, which means you need to say exactly how multiplication is defined on $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the constructions of the various fields do not permit them to be proper subsets or supersets of each other *without proper embedding rules*.  We embed the reals (as constructed) within the complex numbers (as constructed) using a rule such as you might have written $x \to (x, 0)$.

Comment: Similarly, $\mathbb Q$ is not a subset of $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb N$ is not a subset of $\mathbb Z$, right?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/892426/is-a-0i-in-every-way-equal-to-just-a

Comment: Also related: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1055547/622 and http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1327922/622

Comment: Apparently, there are similar questions on MSE but I think that lhf's answer is the best and most concise. Also, title "R is a subset of C?" is much easier to google than "Is a+0i in every way equal to just a?" I don't want users to be redirected. How should I edit my post?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No matter how you define $\mathbb C$, the crucial point is that $\mathbb C$ contains a *copy* of $\mathbb R$, which we still denote by $\mathbb R$, such that $\mathbb C = \mathbb R + i\mathbb R$.

In mathematics, it matters less what things *are* than *how* they behave. If two things behave exactly the same, they're taken to be the same thing, even if the set-theoretic constructions of each do lead to different sets. The technical term is that we consider mathematical objects *up to isomorphism*, where *isomorphism* depends on the context.

This is especially strong when the objects have a categorical characterization that says they are essentially the only possible object with such characteristics. In the case at hand, $\mathbb R$ is *the* complete ordered field and $\mathbb C$ is *the* algebraic closure of $\mathbb R$ (or the *only* algebraic extension of $\mathbb R$ or the *only* quadratic extension of $\mathbb R$).

Comment: Certainly we have $\Bbb R + i \Bbb R = \Bbb C$.  However (and honestly I'm not sure if there's a good answer here), is there any property of the real line $\Bbb R$ that distinguishes it from other lines through $0 \in \Bbb C$?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, yes, the other lines are not subfields of $\mathbb C$.

Comment: right, thanks ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 10):

It is not wrong for you to worry, and the same problem occurs elsewhere:

- We might define $\Bbb Z$ from $\Bbb N_0$ as a set of equivalence classes of $\Bbb N_0^2$ where $(a,b)\sim (c,d)\iff a+d=b+c$. But then $\Bbb N\not\subset \Bbb Z$.
- We might define $\Bbb Q$ as a set of equivalence classes of $\Bbb Z\times \Bbb N$ where $(a,b)\sim (c,d)\iff ad=bc$. But then $\Bbb Z\not\subset \Bbb Q$.
- We might define $\Bbb R$ via Dedekind cuts, which are infinie subsets of $\Bbb Q$; or as equvalence classes of rational Cauchy seequences modulo zero sequences. In both cases, $\Bbb Q\not\subset \Bbb R$.

**But** in each of these cases we have a *canonical* embedding of the smaller object into the larger object which completely respects the algebraic structure. In the above examples we have

- $\Bbb N_0\to \Bbb Z$, $x\mapsto [(x,0)]$
- $\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Q$, $x\mapsto [(x,1)]$ (where $1$ is the element of $\Bbb Z$ of that name, so it is $[(1,0)]$ according to the previous line; note that the $[\ ]$ denote equivalence classes with respect to totally different equivalence relations though)
- $\Bbb Q\to\Bbb R$, $x\mapsto \{\,t\in\Bbb Q\mid t<y\,\}$, respectively $x\mapsto [(x,x,x,x,\ldots)]$

Of course we finde the same for $\Bbb R\to \Bbb C$, be it that we define $\Bbb C=\Bbb R^2$ with suitable operations, or $\Bbb C = \Bbb R[X]/(X^2+1)$.

The canonical nature of these embeddings allows us to loosely identify the smaller set with its image. 
In order to be very formally correct, we can stitch the sets together accordingly: Assume we have two disjoint sets $A,B$ and an injective map $\iota\colon A\to B$, then we can consider the set $\hat B:=(B\setminus \iota(A))\cup A$ instead of $B$ and obtain a set that allows the very same constructions as $B$ does while at the same time having $A$ as a subset. However, it is more cumbersome to try to define e.g. addition on such a stitched set $\hat B$ than to define addition straightforwardly on $B$ and using the canonical embedding to *view* $A$ as a subset of $B$.

During introduction it may be very important to make the distinction between $A$ and $\iota(A)$, but once the desired properties have been established it is best to forget about $\iota$, in fact to forget about the "mechanics" of constructing the larger set. It certainly won't help a physicist in solving his Schrödinger equation if he had to recall that the complex numbers he works with are ordered pairs of equivalence classes of sequences of equivalence classes of ordered pairs of equivalence classes of ordered pairs of finite ordinals (or was it ordered pairs of Dedekind cuts of sequences of equivalence classes of ordered pairs of an equivalence classes of ordered pairs of finite ordinals and a finite ordinal?).

Another justification usually comes as afterthought:

- Given $\Bbb N$ let $\Bbb Z$ be **any** ring that contains $\Bbb N$ as sub-semiring and such that there is no ring $Z$ with $N\subsetneq Z\subsetneq \Bbb Z$. It turns out any two such rings are *canonically* isomorphic - and we need the ordered-pair-construction only to show the existence of such a ring.
- Similarly, let $\Bbb Q$ be any minimal field containing $\Bbb Z$. It turns out any two such fields are canonically isomorphic.
- Similarly, let $\Bbb R$ be any minimal complete field containing $\Bbb Q$. It turns out any two such fields are canonically isomorphic.
- Similarly, let $\Bbb C$ be any minimal algebraically closed field containing $\Bbb R$. Actually, this time  there is *no* canonical isomorphism of any two such fields: What we know as $i\in\Bbb C$ may map to either of two roots of the polynomial $X^2+1$. But once we fix one of these roots and call it $i$, we may consider $\Bbb C$ as $\Bbb R+\Bbb R i$.

Comment: +1 for *ordered pairs of equivalence classes of sequences of equivalence classes of ordered pairs of equivalence classes of ordered pairs of finite ordinals (or was it ordered pairs of Dedekind cuts of sequences of equivalence classes of ordered pairs of an equivalence classes of ordered pairs of finite ordinals and a finite ordinal?)*

Answer (score 0):

From the second definition you gave, the real numbers are just the complex numbers with $b=0$.

Comment: But we used $\mathbb{R}$ in definition of $\mathbb{C}$, so now we can't redefine $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I don't understand your reasoning.

Comment: Why the heck do we need to "redefine" R?  We define integers, then we define "even" using the definition of integer.  What the heck is wrong with *that*?  We don't need to "redefine" integer just because we used in in the definition of a subset or a supraset.

Comment: @fleablood edubrovskiy is saying that if you define $\mathbb{C}$ as the set of $a + bi$ (which is really just going to be implemented as an ordered pair, anyway, if you do it formally) then you can't redefine the real numbers to be the set of ordered pairs where the second coordinate is zero. $\mathbb{R}$ can't be two different sets. This answer needs more detail.

Comment: we don't redefine.  The first definition of Reals still holds, we define C in terms of R, and then we *observe* that R is the subset of C where the second coordinate is zero.  That is not a definition.  It's an observed property--- a fundamental property that we can use axiomatically.

Comment: When we define $\mathbb{C}$ formally, we end up defining it via ordered pairs. Otherwise, we have the problem of what the "$+$" and "$i$" are supposed to mean before we define $\mathbb{C}$. Since a real is not the same as an ordered pair of reals, we do not literally have $\mathbb{R} \subseteq \mathbb{C}$. @fleablood

Comment: That's true, but we still aren't redefining R, we are observing $\{(x,0)| (x,0) \in C\}$ is an isomorphism of R. (Which means we *could* redefine R as such.)

Comment: @CarlMummert Correction: that is *one* of many) ways of defining $\Bbb C$ formally (and not the best in my opinion).

Comment: @fleablood: yes, we agree about that, of course! But when dealing with students it is sometimes important not to use "is" to mean "is isomorphic to". For example it is not typically true that a field "is" a subset of its algebraic closure. That distinction seems to be at the root of the question here.

Comment: I guess I agree.  But we've already broken that practice in defining C as the set of a+bi and as a set of order pairs, when we define relations and functions as ordered pairs and also as relations between single values, etc.  I think in these cases and the "(x,0) \ne x" statement we have a fundamental disconnect between the idea of an ordered pair as simple a way of listing two associated values simultaneously (in which case (x,0) does equal x) and as item in its own right (in which case it doesn't).  It's a bit like confusion about what "sets" are.

Answer (score 0):

$x \ne (x,0)$ but $f: R \times 0 = \{(x,0)\} \rightarrow R$ via $f((x,0)) = x$ is a isoomorphism so $R \cong R \times 0 \subset R^2$

And actually, in a sense, (x,0) *is* the same thing as x.  It's fundamental that we can take two (or more) real numbers put them in an ordered pair and that doing so and creating a third thing, the ordered pair, we aren't actually changing are modifying the two numbers themselves.  For example in the statement y = 2x + 3 the x'es and the y'es *are* real numbers yet we feel no conflict in saying (0,3) is a solution.  How is the zero in the ordered pair supposed to be the same thing as 0, the real number, (0, ~) $\ne$ 0. and (~,3) $\ne$ 3?

Except they are.  To the degree that the abstract concept of  real numbers equaling 0 and 3 exist and there is a set of real numbers, R, is defined.  Then abstract concept of cross referencing them and (0,3) $\in$ RxR where the "0" *is* 0 and the "2" is 2 and the R of the Rx{c} *is* R, is also legitimate.  We can get down into the semantics and/philosophy and/or constructivism as to what embedding the Rs into RxR and view Rx{c} as the "same" as R and what *is* R after all, but in the end.  Rx{c} is isomorphic to R in a fundamental and intuitive way that preserves all concepts, functions, and properties that any distinctions of how Rx{c} *isn't* R is as obscure as the definition of what R "really" is in itself.

(x,0) is equivalent to x in the viewing of R crossed with the single trivial point 0, and that is enough.

==============

$i$ is an element of C but $i$ isn't C.  There is *nothing* wrong with defining a set constructively from previously defined elements.  That's how we define the integers and natural numbers after all.