# Are real numbers a subset of the complex numbers?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I am having an argument with a friend. I think that in a sense, the answer is no. My reasoning is that in linear algebra, a vector $(a, b)$ is not the same as a vector $(a, b, 0)$ because the first one is in $\mathbb{R}^2$, while the second is in $\mathbb{R}^3$. However I am not sure if a similar argument can be made for real vs complex numbers.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}$ is a [subfield of $\mathbb{C}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_extension)

Comment: Recall that the set of complex numbers $\Bbb C$ is defined as $\Bbb C=\{a+ib\mid a,b\in\Bbb R\}$ where $i$ is the imaginary unit. You may see each $a+ib$ as an ordered pair $(a,b)$. What is the subset of $\Bbb C$ in which $b=0$ for every element?

Comment: But (a,b,0) is in $\mathbb R^2 \times {0}$.  Is $\mathbb R^2 \times {0} \ne \mathbb R^2$.  In what sense can that statement be meaningful and true?  Does $\mathbb C = R^2$?  Not really as as $a = a + 0i \in \mathbb R$ but $a + 0i \in \mathbb C$ so ... yes, $\mathbb R \subset \mathbb C$ be any  definition.

Comment: To understand the natural embedding you need to look at the ring / algebra structure, not only the vector space structure. The [Hamilton pair construction](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2658/242) is a normalized version of $\Bbb C \cong R[x]/(x^2+1),\,$ i.e take $\,\Bbb R[x] = $ ring of polynomials with real coefficients, then work modulu $\,x^2+1.\,$  The embedding arises as a composition of two natural maps: $\,r\mapsto r\, x^0,\,$ which maps a real into a constant polynomial, then mapping that to its congruence class mod $\,x^2+1.\,$

Comment: @BillDubuque Not sure you need all that. The embedding $a\to (a,0)$ works rather well.

Comment: @zhw. The point is that if you wish to understand the *ring* (sub)structure then you need more.

Answer (score 0):

Real numbers are just complex numbers with no imaginary part. Linear algebra can get away with saying "a 2-vector is not the same as a 3-vector" because there is no sense of multiplication between vectors. However, real numbers have multiplication, and the complex numbers *extend* the reals by adding i.

Comment: "No imaginary part"? I think you mean "imaginary part = 0". Anyway, real numbers are not complex numbers with zero imaginary part, because complex numbers are elements of $\mathbb R^2. $ What is true is that  the set of complex numbers of the form $(a,0), a \in \mathbb R,$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb R$ in every important mathematical sense you could bring to the table.